# How to combine multiple scripts into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got five of the same scripts that just use five different variables. `#video0` to `#video4`. I'm just not quite sure on how to combine them all so I don't have redundant code. I've been trying to make them all variables

```
var video= [
$('#video0'),
$('#video1'),
$('#video2'),
$('#video3'),
$('#video4')
];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cwfybnzr/

Comment: You can do It in a foor loop: `for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {...}` and in there write `$("#video" + i)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) with the array

```
var videos = [
$('#video0'),
$('#video1'),
$('#video2'),
$('#video3'),
$('#video4')
];

$(function() {
    $.each(videos, function(){
        var iframe = $(this)[0];
        ...
    });
```

});

Comment: @user2252219, ok, whats the reason?

Comment: I think it might just be some semantic issue? http://imdarrien.com/#modal1 If you hit the play button, nothing happens.

Comment: @user2252219, there are javascript errors in the console. Press `F12` and check. Are you including froogaloop2 before jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class element like `videoCSS` to all the elements and then loop through them like

```
$('.videoCSS').each(function(){
    var player = $(this);
    // your code here    
});
```

This way you can future proof you js code as you can add as many new player/iframes to the HTML with `videoCSS` class and your js code will still be the same.

Also, I found that in your code you are doing like

```
var iframe = $('#video0')[0];
var player = $(iframe);
```

Which means that first you are getting a jquery object using `$('#video0')`, then you are trying to get a DOM element out of it like `$('#video0')[0]` and then again you are converting it to a jquery object using `$(iframe)`.

I think there is no need of this much extra processing, you can simply use

```
var player = $('#video0');
```

or using my updated code like

```
var player = $(this);
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cwfybnzr/1/)

Comment: I tried adding a class element to my code but I think the api I'm using only likes IDs. https://jsbin.com/mojopalode/edit?html,css,output

Comment: The code they have here is using a class http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/vimeo/froogaloop2-api-basics.html

Comment: I also created a demo using class based on that: [`Fiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/gbtvxyd8/)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to create class for those elements? Then it will be possible to iterate through them using simple jQuery syntax: `$('.video')`. Plus it would not require changing any JavaScript code when new videos will be added.

Comment: `$('.video').each(function(){ ... });` and in HTML just use: `<video class="video"></video>`.